# Conjugate relation in a group implies conjugate relation in a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $H$ be its normal subgroup of prime index. Take $x\in H$ such that the centralizer of $x$ in group $H$: $C_H(x)$ be a a proper subgroup of the centralizer of $x$ in $G$: $C_G(x)$. Then, if $y\in H$ is conjugate to $x$ in $G$, then $y$ is conjugate to $x$ in H.

I don't know how to tackle this problem. Any hints?

Note that
$|x^G|=\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|}$, $|x^H|=\frac{|H|}{|C_H(x)|}$, $|G|=p|H|$, $|C_H(x)|<|C_G(x)|$, where $x^G$ is a conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$.

We also know that:
$G > H \geq C_H(x)$
and
$G\geq C_G(x)>C_H(x)$.

Comment: @user72829: It's a generic prime or the minimal prime that divides $|G|$ ?

Comment: @WLOG There are no assumptions about prime $p=|G|/|H|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write $p$ for the index of $H$ in $G$ and $q$ for the index of $C_H(x)$ in $C_G(x)$.

Consider the projection homomorphism from $G$ to its quotient $G/H$, and restrict that homomorphism to $C_G(x)$.  That restriction $\rho$ has kernel $C_G(x)\cap H=C_H(x)$, which by assumption is not all of $C_G(x)$.  So the image of $\rho$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $G/H$.  But $G/H$ has prime order, so the image of $\rho$ is all of $G/H$.  That is, $\rho$ induces an isomorphism from $C_G(x)/C_H(x)$ onto $G/H$; so these two groups have the same order, i.e., $p=q$.

Now remember that the number of conjugates of an element in a group is the index of its centralizer.  So if $x$ had strictly more conjugates in $G$ than in $H$, then we'd have $|G|/|C_G(x)|>|H|/|C_H(x)|$, which is equivalent to $p>q$ and thus contradicts what was proved above.